# Symfony: Routing issue add/ {id}/edit

Tags: symfony, routes

I am having an issue with my Routing.

When I try and visit domain.com/listing/add I get the error below

```
Parameter "id" for route "listing_edit" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.
```

I understand with the edit route it will require domain.com/listing/1/edit but I thought having the listing/add route above the edit route I should still be able to visit domain.com/listing/add.

What am I doing wrong?

route.yml

```
listing_add:
        pattern:  listing/add
        defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Listing:add }
 listing_edit:
        pattern:  listing/{id}/edit
        defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Listing:edit}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you use the name of the route? (Inside the html or controller). Apparently you are using the routing name `listing_edit`, where you should use `listing_add` instead.

Comment: probably you are tring to generate the edit link without a stored enity... probably with isnew data

Comment: Thanks @chayasan and @matteo. I was generating the edit route in the add controller with the `id`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using twig, you must use these kind of links:

`<a href="{{ path('listing_add') }}">YOUR LINK TO ADD</a>`

`<a href="{{ path('listing_edit',{'id':entity.id}) }}">YOUR LINK TO EDIT</a>`